# Warned - no cfnRole set and unnecessary files was created after deploy

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, serverless

[No cfnRole warned and unnecessary files was created after deploy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NefS3.png)

```
Serverless: Safeguards Processing...
Serverless: Safeguards Results:

   Summary --------------------------------------------------

   passed - no-unsafe-wildcard-iam-permissions
   passed - framework-version
   warned - require-cfn-role
   passed - allowed-runtimes
   passed - no-secret-env-vars
   passed - allowed-regions
   passed - allowed-stages

   Details --------------------------------------------------

   1) Warned - no cfnRole set
      details: http://slss.io/sg-require-cfn-role
      Require the cfnRole option, which specifies a particular role for CloudFormation to assume while deploying.
```

1. I had been go to the site that write in details.
   details: http://slss.io/sg-require-cfn-role
   Anyway, I don't know how to fix it.
2. s_hello.py & s_hello2.py always generated after deploy.
   This is my serverless.yaml file

```
    service: myapp
    app: sample-app
    org: xxx
    provider:
      name: aws
      runtime: python3.7
    stage: dev
    region: us-east-1

    package:
        individually: true
    functions:
      hello:
        handler: src/handler/handler.hello
      hello2:
        handler: src/handler2/handler2.hello2
```

[It's always happen although follow this site](https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/examples/hello-world/python/) .
My Lambda-function will create "s_xxx.py (Where xxx is handler.py file.

Answer (score 7):

I solved this issue creating a cfn-role in AWS IAM following these steps:

Roles -> Create Role -> AWS Service -> Select **Cloud Formation** from the list

Next: Permisions

You need to choose all the policies you need to deploy your lambda function (S3FullAccess, SQSFullAccess, LambdaFullAccess...)

There's one that it's mandatory **AWSConfigRole** who allows to serverless framework to get this role.

After setting the role, you need to copy its arn and create behind provider level **cfnRole** like this:

```
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: python3.7
  stage: ${opt:stage, 'dev'}
  profile: ${self:custom.deploy-profile.${opt:stage, 'dev'}}
  region: us-west-2
  environment:
    TEMP: "/tmp"
  cfnRole: arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxx:role/cfn-Role
```

That's work for me, I hope to help!